# Capybara Response of AJAX always empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, capybara, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to test a feature thats uses the following JS for an AJAX call:

```
$( "#equipment_input" ).keyup(function(event) {
  if($(this).val() != ''){
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/equipment_search/' + $( "#equipment_input" ).val(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        ...
      }
   });
  }
});
```

The code of controller is:

```
def equipment_by_name
  @equipments = Equipment.where("name like ?", "%" + params[:name] + "%")
  render json: @equipments
end
```

In development environment, the response works fine: I get an array so I can manipulate in JS.
When use the following capybara code to fill the input and render some options for my select:

```
fill_in 'equipment_input', :with => 'B'
```

I get two empty arrays as response.

I'm using `selenium-webdriver`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you actually created any equipment records that would match '%B%' in your test?

Comment: Yes, I created! I can use `byebug` and recover an equipement.

Comment: Have you disabled transactional testing and correctly configured database_cleaner, or are you using Rails 5.1 where the tests and app share a DB connection?  When you say you can use `byebug`, do you mean in your test code, or in your app code?

Comment: we are using rails 5.0, we put a byebug on our controller method and check if we have a equipment saved. The equipment is there, but the ajax response returns an empty array. On development everything works fine.